# How to fix PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

So i'm installing this app on a 3rd laptop, and it's working fine on the other 2, however on this one i'm hitting this psql error whatever rake command i try. Actually no rake command works. I've already tried everything i've seen around here, reinstalled the app, reinstalled the gems, dropped the table from the psql, and i'm totally clueless as to where the issue is. I'm out of ideas. I would assume it's a config problem somewhere .. or some version of something that's creating a conflict

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.7.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/home/allg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:600:in `async_exec': PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "settings" does not exist (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
LINE 1: SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings" ORDER BY "settings"."id...
                                  ^
: SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings" ORDER BY "settings"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
    from /home/allg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:600:in `block in exec_no_cache'
```

Comment: Did you create and migrate the database? `rails db:create` and `rails db:migrate` and seed if necessary?

Comment: as stated above NO rake/rails command works. It throws the exact same error

Comment: yes devise actually does that '  config.mailer_sender = Setting.first.from_email if Setting.first.present?'

Comment: try `config.mailer_sender = Setting.first.from_email if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists? 'settings' && Setting.first.present?`

Comment: i've already fixed the problem by disabling that init line in devise, before doing the migration. mu_is_too_short gave me that idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try `rake db:reset`!

If it doesn't help, try to drop BD!

```
rake db:drop
```

then create new db

```
db:create
```

and run migrate

```
db:migrate
```

also, populate your DB if you have some code in "seed" file!

```
rake db:seed
```

Sometimes if your rake command doesn't work try to add before rake comment in your console:

```
bundle exec
```

Example:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: as already stated -> NO rake command works ... none, well or rather said worked. fixed the problem, it was related to devise